# Is the pointwise supremum of a family of $L^p$ functions also $L^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If $T_t:L^p(X)\to L^p(X),\ t>0,$ are a family of linear operators, we define the *maximal operator* $T^*:L^p(X)\to L^p(X)$ by 
$$T^*f(x)=\sup_{t>0}|T_tf(x)|.$$

This is stated in my notes, but I'm not sure why $T^*f$ as defined necessarily lies in $L^p$ for all $f\in L^p$. Could anyone please clarify this?

Comment: There should be some assumptions on $T_t$; otherwise let $T_tf=tf$.

Comment: It is even worse than that. The equivalence class of $T^\ast f$ depends on the representatives of $T_t f$, in other words, $T^\ast$ is not even well-defined as an operator from $L^p$ to $L^0$ (equivalence classes of measurable functions).

Comment: Some extra conditions are clearly necessary. But if the family is _countable_ and _bounded_ (in $L^p(X)$), then the pointwise supremum is "almost everywhere well defined" in addition to again being in $L^p(X)$. I think this is called Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @s.harp I think the family is indexed over the positive reals, which are of course uncountable. Unfortunately, the intricacies of defining maximal operators in this case are often ignored, even in textbooks.

Comment: Yes I agree, this must just be a mistake from the lecturer as the definition does not make much sense as is. I guess I will need to clarify this.